# Emberjs-1.0.0 template not displaying record

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, handlebars.js, ember-router

In my ember app, the **mail** template only displays when the model passed to **App.MailRoute** is not filtered using filterProperty. This is the **[jsfiddle of the working version not filtered](http://jsfiddle.net/fnU9z/1/)**. Here is the **[jsfiddle that doesn't work after filtering with filterProperty](http://jsfiddle.net/fnU9z/2/)**. The template it uses is the **The mail.handlebars template** and it is pasted underneath the code showing the routes lower down in this question. However, when you comment out the **setupControllers** shown in the code for **App.MailRoute**, everything works as in the **mail.handlebars template** will display the record. But when you **click the fist link** in its parent template that is the **mails.handlebars** template, and then immediately **click the 2nd link** in the parents template, it will throw the error **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'firstChild' of null**. This seems to be caused by the **async: hasMany association between the models**. If I filter the content of **App.MailRoute**, it doesn't throw the error above when I **click the 1st link** and then **immediately click the 2nd link** but thought there is no error, the template doesn't display anything even when the console shows that the model was populated with the right data.

**The router**

```
App.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('mails', function() {
    this.resource('mail', { path: ':id' });
  });
});
```

**The App.MailsRoute**

```
App.MailsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return this.store.find('mail');    
  }
});
```

**The App.MailRoute**

```
 App.MailRoute = Em.Route.extend({
    setupController: function(controller, model) {
       console.log('model', model);

       a = this.controllerFor('mails').filterProperty('id', model.id);
       console.log('a', a);

      controller.set('model', a);
      console.log('model after setupcontroller', model);
    } 

 });
```

**The mails.handlebars template**

```
<script type='text/x-handlebars' data-template-name='mails'>
  <h6> from mails template </h6>
  {{#each item in  model}}
   {{#link-to 'mail' item }} {{item.name}} ( {{item.messages.length}} ) {{/link-to}}
  <br/>
  {{/each}}
  {{outlet}}
</script>
```

**The mail.handlebars template**

```
<script type='text/x-handlebars' data-template-name='mail'>
 <br/>

  {{log record}}
 {{controller}}
<h6> individual mail template </h6>

  {{type}} or {{name}}

  <div>
  <table>
  <tr>
  <th>From</th>
  <th>To</th>
  <th> Subject </th>
  <th> Body </th>
  <th>Date</th>
  </tr>

 {{#each messages}}

     <td>{{from}}</td>
     <td>{{to}}</td>
    <td>{{subject}}</td>
    <td>{{body}}</td>
     <td> {{date}}</td>
     <br/>
 {{/each}}
 </table>

  {{outlet}}
</div>
```

**The App.Mail model**

```
App.Mail = DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  type: DS.attr('string'),
  messages: DS.hasMany('message', {async: true})
});
```

**The App.Message Model**

```
App.Message = DS.Model.extend({
  subject: DS.attr("string"),
  from: DS.attr("string"),
  to: DS.attr("string"),
  date: DS.attr('date'),
  body: DS.attr("string"),
  mail: DS.belongsTo('mail')
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The real problem is the table.  If you look at all of the data without the table structure it works.  Adding everything back in you'll notice the 
 which breaks it.  Remove that and you should be good.

Additionally you should implement the model hook or refresh won't work.

```
{{#each messages}}

    <td>{{from}}</td>
    <td>{{to}}</td>
    <td>{{subject}}</td>
    <td>{{body}}</td>
    <td>{{date}}</td>

{{/each}}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fnU9z/3/

Comment: Many thanks @kingpin2k. Do you know why **<br/>** tag was causing that problem. I don't need the **<br/>** tag but thought I should ask you if you have any explanation for learning sake.

Comment: Tables are tricky in Ember, and extra tags seems to break the view builder.  I'm not positive on the exact reason.

Comment: Yuck I got the same error from a similar reason - inside of a table : /

Answer (score 1):

your problem is that you're assigning an array here:

```
controller.set('model', a);
```

a is an array, filterProperty returns an array, you need to pass only one element.

I think you need to use findByProperty, it depends in the ember version you're using. It could be that findBy works for you

Comment: I think you need to use findByProperty, it depends in the ember version you're using. It could be that findBy works for you.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, please note **it is not me that downvoted you**. Using **findBy** works but it takes me back to the situation where when I click the 1st link and immediately click the 2nd link, I get the error **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'firstChild' of null**.

Comment: sure, don't worry, glad someone else gave you the right answer.

Comment: lol, it was totally me, it was an accident tho, shoulder surgery has me using my left hand, and i missed, then tried to fix it, but it said I couldn't change the vote unless it was edited, so i edited your post then fixed it ;)